# occurence of a n-sigma event in symmetric distribution

Tags: distributions, kurtosis

Is it possible to approximate the frequency of occurence of a n-sigma event in a symmetrical (skew=0) unimodal distribution with mean/mode/median=0, but with fat tails, with given kurtosis =k.

I was thinking on the lines of approximating the distribution with a t-distribution. The variance of t-dist with v degrees of freedom is v/(v-2) for v>2, and excess kurtosis = 6/(v-4) for v>4. So, given the var and kurtsosis of my distribution, I might not get the same values for v.

The best I can do so far is use Chebyshev to come up with the limits. But given that my distribution is better defined, I was hoping to get a tighter limit.

Comment: As you can read elsewhere here on CV, the relationship between kurtosis and fatness of tails is tenuous at best and almost worthless for arbitrary multiples of $\sigma.$  What else can you say about the distributional shape and the weight of its tails?

Comment: See here, particularly my last comment, for a nice connection to kurtosis: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/369789/102879

Comment: See also here for mathematical results relating kurtosis to tails beyond multiples of sigma. @whuber is not characterizing the state of CV and the extant literature correctly.https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4321753/

Comment: @BigBendRegion As in many other places on this site, you misrepresent my opinions. Of course the weight of tails tells us something about kurtosis: but it doesn't work in the other direction, as I have demonstrated repeatedly in other posts.  It requires an idiosyncratic concept of tail "heaviness" to make any such converse deduction.

Comment: Idiosyncratic? And your definition of tail heaviness is not similarly idiosyncratic? There are infinitely many definitions, so why that one in particular? Especially when it cannot even be directly used on a data set?